# REGEX to cover just first match from all

Tags: regex, regex-group, regexp-replace

I have this type of regex

```
\b[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```

It's not complete, this will match me many examples of 5 digit but I need just first and one match from this structure:

```
Reference Number            WW  
30966                     CFUN22       098765334    
30967                     CFUN22       098765335

30968                     CFUN22       098765336        
30969                     CFUN22    098765337
```

In this case I need just "30966" , not 30967,30968 and so on...

I tried to do

```
\b[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\b
```

Comment: With which tool/language ?

Comment: need to match me on  https://regex101.com/r/7uCnTg/1  with global flag on! I tried already just with insensitive, but I need also global

Comment: Thanks to check [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75177684/edit) to format your code as I've done for next times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a positive lookbehind to make sure that you're grabbing the first 5-digit number after the word "Comments":

```
(?<=Comments\n)\d{5}\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/pZLj4K/1

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following regex:

```
^\N+\n.*?(\d{5})
```

It will match:

- `^`: start of string
- `\N+\n`: any sequence of non-newline characters, followed by newline
- `\n`: the newline character
- `.*?`: optional smallest sequence of characters
- `(\d{5})`: "*Group 1*" - sequence of five characters

Your needed digits can be found within Group 1.

Given you're dealing with a textual table, using `\N\n` will allow you to skip the header from selection, while `.*?` will allow to match your code not necessarily at the beginning of the second line.

Check the regex demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/tdA4yE/1).